# Load a Material Select with mutiple options with some options checked?

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to implement a Material Select with multiple options (like [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pboolkprnpm?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)).  But I want to populate the certain checkboxes on page load based on data returned from the api.  How would I do this?  I can't find a `checked` or `selected` property anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have two possibilities:

In your example, you are using **Reactive form**, so in ngOnInit event hook, you could set the value of your formControl, something like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.toppings.setValue(['Onion', 'Mushroom'])
  }
```

If you prefer **template driven**, instead of `[(value)]` try `[(ngModel)]`, something like this :

```
// some html template
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected" multiple>
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the component :

```
selected = ['Onion', 'Mushroom']
```

Here is a [demo with the two possibilities](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrdq6r?file=app/select-multiple-example.html), choose whatever make your pizza :)